# replay btn in flash cs6 using actionscript 3 is not behaving correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs6

I have a flash animation that using action script at the end to stop the animation and has a button for the user to click and replay at the animation. When they click and replay the animation the last scenes that were on the screen don't disappear as the animation restarts. My button has an instance name of replay_btn. Any suggestions?

my action script code is

```
  stop();

    import flash.events.MouseEvent; function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {  gotoAndPlay(1); } replay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

This has been answered now. It seem like there was a bug in flash causes the last scenes to hang while replay the start of the animation. The workaround was to make the replay button go forward one frame to a blank white frame and then direct it back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed the button is inside the movieclip you want to startover.

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    replay_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(1);
}
replay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

Comment: Yes the button is inside of the animation that i want to replay after it finishes. When I put your code in - I get an error instead of the the movie replaying it throws up this code TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  I only use flash once every 6 months so don't have a clue where to start looking.
 at SMS_XMAS_fla::MainTimeline/frame1057()

Comment: Where had you put up this code, in the same frame where your button is in? Are you sure your button has scope? Try to trace your button `trace(replay_btn)` in the very first line and see what it returns. If it returns `null` the problem is with button or let us see what will be the problem.